# Testing 2 Stage Bootloader on VirtualBox

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, masm, bootloader, x86-16

I am trying to develop 16 bit  sample 2 stage boot loader using visualstudio 1.5 and want to test on the virtual box.

My sample code is

```
    _TEXT   SEGMENT WORD USE16 'CODE'
    ASSUME  CS:_TEXT, DS:_TEXT, ES:_TEXT


    DATAAREA        EQU 7A00H


ORG     0600H   

StartFromSecondSector:
    jmp     near ptr SecondSector
    nop
    ORG     0600H


SecondSector:
        ; Boot Code

ORG DATAAREA    
    is_ext      db  0

ORG     7C00H
ASSUME  CS:_TEXT, DS:_TEXT, ES:_TEXT    

main:

    ;segment registers and stack Init Code
        xor ax, ax          
        mov ds, ax
        mov es, ax
        cli                 
        mov ss, ax          
        mov sp, 4F00H   ; Stack Top
        sti

        ; Check Disk Extension  
        ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D42h:_Extended_Read_Sectors_From_Drive

        mov     dl, 80h
        mov     ah, 41h
        mov     bx, 55aah
        int     13h 
        setnc    is_ext 

        ; Get Disk Detail
        ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D08h:_Read_Drive_Parameters     

        mov     dl, 80h
        mov     ah, 08h
        int     13h

        cmp     bx, 0aa55h
        je      LoadBootSector 

        jmp     ErrorMSGPrompt 


    LoadBootSector:
        mov     bx, 600h
        mov     ah, 42
        mov     dl, 80h
        int     13h

        jmp     StartFromSecondSector

        ORG     7C00H+1BEH  
        DB      64 DUP (0FFH)   

        DB      055H        
        DB      0AAH 
        ErrorMSGPrompt:
            ; Error mesage int10
        _TEXT       ends    
end     main
```

After Assembling and making and 16 bit executable , i remove the EXE signature and placed the binary in 2 file . 1 stage0.DAT which contains the 512 bytes of code started from 7c00 and another file is stage1.DAT which contains the next 512 bytes of started from 600 offset.

In virtualbox vdi HDD of fixed size , i copied the 512 byte of stage0.dat from 0200000 to 2001F0 and i copied the 512 bytes of stage1.DAT from 0200600 to 02007F0

The stage0 works fine but the jump to the stage 2 is failing. is i am missing some thing ?

Comment: simplifying the question , if i am going to test a 2 stage bootloader , my stage 0 code of 512 byte will be placed at 0200000 offset with the signature of 55AA , But what should be the location of code stage 2 for interrupt INT 13h AH=42h so that i can load this in stack and load the kernel

Comment: I'll assume you mean Visual C++ 1.5. As for MASM 1.5, maybe MASM 6.x? When you say _ i copied the 512 byte of stage0.dat from 0200000_ I assume you mean **TO** 0200000 not **from**

Comment: Your code isn't a minimal complete verifiable example so it likely won't get the attention you are hoping for.

Comment: Yes its Visual Studio 1.5 with CL.exe . I made 1 16 bit binary with this help. On virtualbox header its offset 150 that describe oth sector , so i copied the 1st 512 from  0200000 . That is from 0200000  to 2001F0 .The stage 1 code is placed from 0200600 to 0200B12 .

Comment: For one thing you don't use [int 13/ah=2](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm) correctly. The second sector is at Cylinder 0, Head 0, Sector 2 (sectors start counting from 1). If you are trying to read the second sector you need to tell it that. Number of sectors to read in _AL_ (has to be at least 1), CH is the cylinder which in this case needs to be 0; _CL_ is the sector number which needs to be 2 in your case, and _DH_ is the head number which needs to be 0 in your case.

Comment: As well in the disk image I'm not sure why you are placing the second sector starting at 0200600. Second sector (right after the master boot record) is 0200200 in the file.

Comment: Thanks Sir .. I will check with this changes .